# How can I minimize all windows on a remote computer using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell, ssh

I've been trying to use PowerShell on Windows 10 remote computer using SSH to minimize all windows.
This is what I tried:

```
hostname = MYHOST
username = MYUSER
password = MYPASSWORD
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(hostname=hostname, username=username, password=password)

command = 'powershell (New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application").MinimizeAll()'
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(command, timeout=30)
```

However, this returns nothing and does not perform the task on the remote computer.

This command works on my computer when I run it using *subprocess.Popen*

Can anyone help? I am also open to other suggestions, not necessarily PowerShell, I just figured it should be the best option.

Edit:
If it helps, I also tried bypassing execution policy, in case it prevents me from running from remote machine, so I did this: (again, working locally but on remote does not work)

```
ssh_client.execute_command('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command "& { $x = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application; $x.minimizeall() }"')
```

Comment: Something that I have run into before and might be worth looking into is that ssh with windows doesn't grant you access to the desktop therefore commands that work on your local system won't work through ssh. For instance you cannot take screenshots or create keyboard events. This might be a case of that.

Comment: Thanks. I also thought about running a script from remote, this way the script will be local and will be able to perform this task. I could upload the script to the remote computer via ssh when I need it. But I still prefer avoiding using this script method.

Comment: You’re running the script as the user that’s logged in?

Comment: @doug-maurer, My computer's username and the remote computer's username are different, if that's what you were asking. I can run other simple PowerShell commands on the remote computer.

Comment: Running commands on the remote computer and interacting with an interactive logon session are two very different things. If you want to open anything in that session you will need to run as that user.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. In the end I made it possible using a script which sits on the remote computer, which I am running by SSH and using direct win32 API commands to locate the windows I want and manipulate them.